# Roommate agreements

Tags: united-states, contract-law, lease, virginia

I am renting a 3-bedroom townhouse with 2 other people. Before we renewed the lease, I told them that my fiancé would be moving to this country and would need to move in. I agreed then to pay a certain higher percentage of the rent. Now that he is coming, they are now saying I need to pay an even higher percentage. I would not have resigned the lease if I knew that. Can they force me to pay a higher percentage if the landlord approves of him moving in? I am in Virginia.

Comment: Did you write anything down or was that a verbal agreement ?

Comment: In what name is the lease in?  What are the percentages?  What is the square footage impact (eg: bigger bedroom, etc.)?

Comment: How would you prove that the other two people agreed to the former percentage? what reasons are they giving for demanding now an even higher percentage? what are the current, agreed, and required percentages?